# What is the right way to add css class to this?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change the label of a button after it is clicked. I tried to add CSS class to the return value so that I can use it to style.

This is the code

```
//Rename the button on the Product page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'ts_product_add_cart_button' );
 
function ts_product_add_cart_button( $label ) {
    
   foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
      $product = $values['data'];
      if( get_the_ID() == $product->get_id() ) {
         $label = __('Already added to Cart', 'woocommerce');
      }
   }
    
   return $label;
 
}
 
//Rename the button on the Shop page 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'ts_shop_add_cart_button', 99, 2 );
 
function ts_shop_add_cart_button( $label, $product ) {
    
   if ( $product->get_type() == 'simple' && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ) 
   {
       
      foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
         $_product = $values['data'];
         if( get_the_ID() == $_product->get_id() ) {
            $label = __('Already added to Cart', 'woocommerce');
         }
       }    
   }
    return $label;    
}
```

This is the closest that I managed but with `echo`. However, it messed up the appearance and alignment of the button.

```
 echo '<span style=background:yellow;>'. $label . '</span>';
```

I also tried

```
 $label = __('<span style=background:yellow;>Added to cart</span>', 'woocommerce');
```

Comment: An observation - you need quotes around the background:yellow; in the style setting that you are echoing. Could you use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see what CSS is actually being set.

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth after several tries, I think I have to use `return` instead of `echo`. However, I do not know how to add css class into the return value.

Comment: The filter hook(s) you use are for text editing only. Not for applying/modifying a CSS class. Since you also apply this on the shop page, I assume that Ajax is disabled there?

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r Ajax is enabled. Should it be disabled?

Comment: That is not necessary, but then your code must be designed for it and that is not the case with your current code. The text will not adjust itself after adding a product to the cart, unless you refresh the page

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r The code works fine with changing the button label. The problem is unable to add a css class for markup.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce has two hooks which will let you wrap the button in your custom markup, and using that you can access the button in the javascript to change the label? Something as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'before_button_markup' );

function before_button_markup(){
    echo '<div class="custom-button">';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'after_button_markup' );

function after_button_markup(){
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if it is because I did it wrong. I use these two hooks and it doesn't add css class.

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake. I was checking on the shop page. It does add a css class on the single product page. I suppose the shop page uses a different set of hooks?

Comment: After several attempts, I could be doing it wrong, the hooks are unable to differentiate if the item is already added to cart.